# In the about-new page hovering the title area shows a dotted line at the bottom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about-new

The dotted line **when hovering** does not belong there. It is bothering me and distracting from all the other awesome that page is dripping with. Kill it with fire, please.

It looks like this (please excuse the freehand red mouse cursor):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Could you add some free hand circles?

Comment: I don't see the dots, but I do see this http://i.stack.imgur.com/6n5Aw.png arg

Comment: @StrixVaria Thank you. I saw the free handed cursor and instinctively, compulsively clicked the upvote button - only to be told that I can't upvote that fine piece of art. _OH CRUEL WORLD!_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a on-hover glitch I fixed yesterday on dev before we officially turned on the new About page for this site. Are you still seeing the on-hover dotted line? I'm [not seeing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) it right now

Comment: Yeah, it's been fixed.